# Как сделать sql запрос проще

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

У меня есть таблица, в нем имеется сообщения пользователей. [image: Таблица базы данных]

Так вот для того чтобы получить id последних переписок с пользователями (id=1) я использую этот запрос:

```
SELECT
      (
        SELECT id FROM messages m1 
        WHERE m1.conversationId = M.conversationId 
        ORDER BY m1.id DESC LIMIT 1
      ) AS 'id'
FROM messages M
WHERE (M.fromId = 1 OR M.toId = 1)
GROUP BY m.conversationId
```

Можно ли сделать запрос проще??

Дополнения:
Каждой переписке присваивается отдельное conversationId. Например переписка между пользователями 1 и 3 имеет conversationId=1, а переписка между пользователями 1 и 2 имеет conversationId=2.

Comment: На данный момент я вижу запрос, выводящий максимальные id для тех `conversationId`, которые бывают у сообщений заданного пользователя. Причем максимальные глобально, без учета пользователя. Расскажите что это за conversationId и какова на самом деле задача данного запроса

Comment: Каждой переписке присваивается отдельное conversationId. Например переписка между пользователями 1 и 3 имеет conversationId=1, а переписка между пользователями 1 и 2 имеет conversationId=2.

Comment: Т.е. у вас не может быть ситуации, что один conversationId есть для записей с пользователями 1 и 2 и он же в записях с пользователями 2 и 3 или даже 3 и 4 ?

Comment: Да @Mike . Например conversationId 2 только для пользователей 1 и 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может такой вариант ?

```
select max(id)
  from messages M
 where M.fromId = 1 OR M.toId = 1
 group by m.conversationId
```

Выбирает практически то же, что и ваш запрос, но только среди записей с данными пользователями.

Comment: Да спасибо. то что хотел))

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM messages
WHERE fromId = 1 OR toId = 1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Пробовал, выдается id первой сообщения переписки, а мне нужен последний. То есть должно выводиться id 162 и 166

Answer (score 1):

Запрос который вы используете, не соответствует той задаче, которую вы решаете.
Вероятно, вам нужно более подробно раскрыть задачу.
Для решения же указанной задачи достаточно выполнить:

```
SELECT id
FROM messages
WHERE fromId = 1 OR toId = 1
GROUP BY id
```

С учетом изменений в постановке получается так:

```
SELECT m.conversationId, max(m.id) id
FROM messages m
WHERE (m.fromId = 1 OR m.toId = 1)
GROUP BY m.conversationId
```

Comment: Ваш код попросту выводит все id в котором есть fromId = 1 OR toId = 1 .А должно учитываться поле conversationId и должно выводиться только id 162 и 166. Это значит из каждой conversationId выводить только последнюю строку в котором fromId = 1 OR toId = 1. Надеюсь уточнил @Ermine